# Creating a proccess dump via CMD or Powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd, procdump

**Welcome** i have ran into a small issue. So basically i have been coding a program to open up power-shell and run proc dump and dump a process. Using Proc Dump. I keep getting multiple processes running. And there is no way i can get the PID, So its useless. Is there another third party tool that i can use without getting this issue? or can i just do this via CMD or power-shell without using other software's? Thanks!

Error im receiving

```
Multiple processes match the specified name.
```

Comment: The error you are receiving from exactly **what** ?

Comment: @LotPings - that is an errror from procdump when there are multiple processes with an identical name.

Answer (score 1):

I have used following powershell command in the past to create a procdump of multiple processes with an identical name

```
gps notepad* | %{ 
    $argumentList = "-accepteula -ma -n 1000 -e 1 $($_.Id) "
    start-process C:\My\SysInternals\procdump -argumentList $argumentList
}
```

The gist of this is to get a list op PID's to pass to procdump. Mind you that when you have dozens of notepads running, you'll create dozens of dumps.